# How to sort by meta value num, but ignore zero value?

Tags: post-meta, sort, meta-value

I have custom-post-type `company` and taxonomy `services` for this CPT.
I have created meta-field `service_[id]_price` for companies and fill this field with a number. If this company has not price for this service, I fill 0 in this field.

On the services page, I need a list of companies sorted by current service price ASC. In this case, I first get all companies with "0" value in this field. But I need to get all companies where this field has not zero value in ASC order - first, and all that have value '0' at the end.

Comment: consider not saving anything under the key if there is no price, rather than zero. you can query for posts both where a meta key does and does not exist, and have the posts where it does exist appear first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *meta_query* in your WP_Query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'company',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'service_XXXX_price',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
    ),
);
$company_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can find more infos about the meta querys in the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: In this case I just exclude services with price = 0. But I need to get all companies and sort it: Part-1: with service price > 0 in ASC order, Part-2: with service price = 0

Comment: I think I need to JOIN two queries here...

Comment: You can use an if-statement.
If the value is 0, then copy it in an array, else echo the post.
At the end you can echo the posts from the 0-array